# Refer to ascx Controls inside a Panel

Tags: c#, webforms, panel, ascx

I've inherited an ASP.NET application which has a page where UserControls are added dynamically to a panel (or ContentPlaceHolder), each UserControl having several controls to display information and a RadioButtonList which accepts user input.  The validation of the form and the database update are triggered from a submit button on the main.aspx page which contains the panel with the controls in it.  This works absolutely fine.

So I have replicated the idea on another page (as a different ascx containing different controls) by copying the code/logic and modifying it as this is the only way I know how to add a variable number of controls (each control has a heading, displays some information and has a CheckBox for user input).

The new UserControls are added to the page fine, the problem comes when I try to refer to them using the code below.  This code is fired from a Submit button.  It fails because the panel object contains no controls, despite them being **displayed** on the webpage when I test!

```
protected void GetInformationSelected()
    {
        int numRecs = 0;
        foreach (Control c in pnlInfo.Controls) // this is the problem as no controls are detected inside the panel
        {
            try
            {
                string x = c.GetType().ToString();
                if (x == "ASP.ctlInfo_ascx")
                {
                    if (((ctlInfo)c) != null)
                    { 
                        numRecs = numRecs + ((ctlInfo)c).getSelected();  // this will read the value from the control
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception err)
            {
                Response.Write(err.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm sure further information is required to describe the problem and I'll happily post whatever else is required.

Here is how I add the control to the Panel.  Of interest was the fact that using `this.FindControl("pnlInfo").Controls.Add(c1);` did not work as it had in the other page and instead I used simply `pnlInfo.Controls.Add(c1);`

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            ctlInfo c1 = (ctlInfo)this.LoadControl("~\\ctlInfo.ascx");
            c1.Init(Int32.Parse(dr[0].ToString()), dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString());  // *** need to check the columns in the data set
            pnlInfo.Controls.Add(c1);
            //this.FindControl("pnlInfo").Controls.Add(c1);  This is how the previous example added the controls, note the subtle difference
        }
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated so thanks in advance.  Below I show what Is displayed in the webpage, with the offending panel containing the 5 User Controls on the right of the screen.  Note that always the product information is shown (i.e. add the first UserControl) but there may be between 0 and 4 additional bits of info displayed based on a random component to the experiment:

[image: Screenshot of the main page with 5 x User Controls added to the right hand side]

Comment: Could you post your ASPX code that has the panel? When (in the lifecycle) do you check the whether this panel has any controls? Could this be before you add them?

Comment: @bump it's a lot of code given that there are about 4 levels in the Call Stack but the code to Add the controls (shown at the bottom of my post) is called from the Page_Load of the main page.  So they are certainly added, hence I can see them when the webpage opens.  The check to see if they exist is later on when the user clucks the submit button on the main form.
I'm going to have to create a reproducible example aren't I?  There goes my Saturday afternoon....!

Comment: Instead of adding your controls dynamically you could perhaps look at using an asp:Repeater control. This will likely be easier to manage in the long run. You can get a lot of issues adding controls dynamically

Comment: @geedubb Thanks for the suggestion and it's a convenient way to display information but I need the Checkbox in every row to accept optional user input.  The asp:Repeater is not updatable is it?

Comment: You have to re-add the controls on postback.